# Which event get fired first when an ExtJS grid inside a view is loaded

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, extjs-grid

I have a view, which contains a grid. The grid is having a grouping feature. I am enabling/disabling the feature based on user interaction. If I disable the feature & close the window, the next time I load the view, the grouping feature remains disabled.

I am wondering, How can i say, as soon as grid is loaded, enable the group feature in the grid. Do we have any event or method to achieve this?

Thanks !!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could just enable the feature in the afterrender event of the grid

```
listeners: {
    afterrender: function() {
        // fancy grouping code
        // I'm not really familiar with grouping, 
        // so I can't provide code for this part
    }
}
```

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-event-afterrender